# Get nearest point on a sphere in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, distance, dot-product

I want to get the point on a n-dimensional sphere, which is nearest to a given point `p` with the same dimension.

My sphere is created by the dot-product of a positive definite Matrix `A`.
All points on the sphere are characterized by:

```
x'*A*x = const
```

Mathematically, I am searching for the `x` where

```
(p-x)'*A*(p-x)
```

is minimal. (`x` is a point on the sphere)

I didn't find any MATLAB function for this problem, nor do I have an idea on how to solve this problem in `n` dimensions.

Comment: The tricky bit is constraining yourself to the sphere. The minimum search would be easy with `fminsearch()`. If you can somehow parametrize the points on your sphere with `n-1` coordinates, then you can just drop the distance into `fzero`. I guess something like `fminbnd` might be of use, but I have zero experience with that.

Comment: Isn't your (hyper)sphere actually a (hyper)ellipsoid?

Comment: Thank you very much, gonna test this out. Mathematically it is a sphere, geometrically it can be an ellipsoid.